# Show that the MLE divided by the true value converges to 1

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

Let $S \sim Binomial(N,\theta)$, where $S$ can be seen as $S_n = B_1+...+B_N$ and $B_i$'s are i.d.d $Bernoulli(\theta)$.

I have to show that $\frac{\hat{N}_{MLE}}{N}$ converges to $1$ in probability as $N$ goes to infinity.

I know that $\hat{N}_{MLE}$ is the smallest integer $>\frac{S}{\theta}-1$.

I think I have to use the weak law of large numbers, but I am not sure how to find $E[\hat{N}_{MLE}]$, (maybe it's $E[\frac{S}{\theta}-1]=\frac{n\theta}{\theta}-1$?), or how to find $E[N]$.

Comment: I guess you mean $\hat{\theta} \overset{P}{\rightarrow}\theta$

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain this?

Comment: When dealing with the limiting behavior of an expression involving random variables, you need to specify the type of convergence (e.g. convergence in probability, almost sure convergence, etc.). Deep North's notation refers to convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your knowledge about $\hat N_{MLE}$, we can first deduct the inequality
$$\frac{S_N}\theta-1<\hat N_{MLE}\le \frac{S_N}\theta.$$
We also know (or can prove easily) that $E\left[\frac{B_1}\theta\right]=1$.
Thus, using the LLN for $S_N=B_1+\dots+B_N$, we get
$$\frac{S_N}{N\theta}\overset{P}\longrightarrow 1.$$
Now, rewriting our inequality (for $N\ne0$) yields
$$\frac{\hat N_{MLE}}N\le \frac{S_N}{N\theta},$$
which we can use to prove convergence in distribution:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{\hat N_{MLE}}N-1\right|>\epsilon\right)\le\lim_{N\to\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{S_N}{N\theta}-1\right|>\epsilon\right)=0,$$
for all $\epsilon>0$.